# Is there any way to perform this type of recursion in C++ or python?

Tags: python, c++, recursion, euclidean-algorithm

Let us say I have a function called `my_func(a,b,s,t)`. Suppose, I want `a` and `b` to be passed by value, but I want `s` and `t` to be passed by reference. As in, I want to some how pass in let us say `(4,5,s',t')`. The function performs computations by calling `my_func(a/2,b/2,s/2,t/2)`. The thing is, there is a base case at the "bottom" of the recursion that gives concrete values to `s` and `t`.

Let me give a mini example:

```
def e_euclid(a,b,s,t):
    
if (a == b):
    s = 4
    t = -3
    return a


if (a%2 == 0 and b%2 == 0):
    
    if (s%2 == 0 and t%2 == 0):
        return 2*e_euclid(a/2,b/2,s/2,t/2)
    else:
        return 2*e_euclid(a/2,b/2,(s+b)/2,(t-a)/2)
...
```

So, I would call this function as `e_euclid(a,b, something, something)` but then I would have to supply concrete values for `s` and `t`. Can you guys kind of see what I'm trying to do here?

Doing recursion where I return (s,t) would lead to a tough computation that I don't wish to perform, so I would like to do it this way.

Comment: Pass 6 parameters - a, b, s, and t by value, and also s and t by reference; pass the last two down recursive calls unchanged. Or, have the function return a tuple of `{a, s, t}` rather than a single value, then you won't need by-ref parameters. Or, don't use recursion at all: the example involves tail recursion, which could be trivially replaced by iteration.

Comment: So, you don't want to specify the values for the 3rd and the 4th parameter until the recursion stops, and then you somehow want to figure out what the 3rd and the 4th parameter's value shold've been right from the begining. Sorry, no modern general purpose programming language works like that. How do you expect to know what `s` and `t` are, in the expression `if (s%2 == 0 and t%2 == 0)`, when those values are not known until the recursion ends?

Comment: You should rewrite this iteratively. Keep a list as a stack, and push values along with return multiplications into it. There would be no recursion and a nice `while not stack.is_empty()`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I don't quite understand their code attempt, but see my answer for how it's done. The values `s` and `t` (or `x` and `y`) are indeed only specified at the bottom of the recursion, where that's trivial because the `a` and `b` that they correspond to have become trivial. And on the way back up out of the recursion, indeed we compute what `x` and `y` "should've been right from the beginning" (i.e., corresponding to the initial `a` and `b`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems broken, already that base case (?) with `a == b` and `s = 4` and `t = -3` doesn't make sense. But see [this C++ implementation](https://cp-algorithms.com/algebra/extended-euclid-algorithm.html#toc-tgt-1) and my Python translation using single-element lists instead of C++'s references:

```
def gcd(a, b, x=[None], y=[None]):
    if b == 0:
        x[0] = 1
        y[0] = 0
        return a
    x1, y1 = [None], [None]
    d = gcd(b, a % b, x1, y1)
    x[0] = y1[0]
    y[0] = x1[0] - y1[0] * (a // b)
    return d

a, b = 123, 321
x, y = [None], [None]
print(gcd(a, b, x, y), x, y, a*x[0] + b*y[0])
```

Output ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNDoMgEIX3nOJtmoilUXTTNOEKvYBxAUVbN9YYm@Dp6QDWmHQ2A29@3gfTurzeY32dZu9t1@P5sJkWMAJONff32LUC63biNwaKoYeBUijTNYRryhYKchfWJJS7MHfLZx6ho@AkLZVU/zmkHGuW5ABBBBqnCBK7OTsYrZIyOxi5IOCSCsiRaRQFTBravC1j4WWBs6oF6koyR5v/MaZ5GJfs8BPUxVMiqDwynGHy4M29/wI)):

```
3 [47] [-18] 3
```

I think you're trying to use the binary version of the algorithm, that should be doable the same way.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. I realized what I have been trying to do is impossible, so I'm forced to do it by returning (a,b,s,t) which is equivalent to this method.